# How do I display randomly-chosen text with an associated image?

Tags: javascript, quotes, dynamic-linking, page-refresh

I'm a beginner web designer and I need to know how can I link one thing to another. The thing is that I'm making different quotes change every time the site refreshes. 
And I need to do the same thing with images that are located in a different div tag. The reason I need to link them is because the image needs to coordinate with the quote. 
For example: quote 0 with image 0.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var quotes=new Array();
quotes[0] = "text1";
quotes[1] = "Text2";
quotes[2] = "text3";
quotes[3] = "text4";

var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));
function showquote(){document.write(quotes[whichquote]);}
showquote();
```

And this is the code that is located the javascript text:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="quotes.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need link JavaScript to JavaScript. It sounds like you have to coordinate the JavaScript and whatever it is generating the images.

Comment: Thank you! And do you know how can I do that?

Comment: FYI (because you're new at JavaScript): There's almost never any reason to use `new Array`. Use an array literal. In this case: http://pastie.org/8137855 Separately, the `language` attribute was deprecated in the 90's, and the default value of `type` on `script` is `text/javascript`. So just `<script src="..."></script>` is all you need. Sorry, and your random number is wrong. You want `=Math.round(Math.random() * q)`, not `q-1`.

Comment: @ user: It's impossible to say, you haven't shown anything telling us how the images are chosen.

Comment: The thing is that I still don't know how can I put the images, and I can't find a tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes on that code. Don't take these the wrong way, you're new to JavaScript! Everyone was once, having people point things out is one way we learn.

1. There's almost never any reason to use `new Array`. Use an array literal. In this case:

   ```
   var quotes = [
       "text1",
       "Text2",
       "text3",
       "text4"
   ];
   ```
2. The `language` attribute was deprecated in the 90's, and the default value of `type` on `script` is `text/javascript`. So just `<script src="..."></script>` is all you need.
3. Your random number is wrong. `Math.random` returns a number from `0` (inclusive) to `1` (**exclusive**), so you want to just multiply by the number of images, not the number minus one.
4. `document.write` is best avoided. There's very, very little reason to use it in modern web programming.

Here's one way to approach doing what you described: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/arukov/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/arukov/1/edit)

*(You have to refresh it a lot, because it only has two entries, so you have pretty good odds of seeing the same one.)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Random Text Plus Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "text1",
          img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
        },
        {
          text: "text2",
          img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
        }
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I did there:

- I output an element, the `<div id="quote"></div>`, to hold the quote and image. This is instead of the `document.write`.
- I used an array literal, but my array literal contains *object* literals (the `{...}` things with `text: "text1"` and such in them). So my array contains objects, where each object has the properties `text` (the text of that quote) and `img` (the URL of the image to use).
- I fixed the random thing.
- When outputting the text (which I assume is HTML markup) and the image, I do that by setting `innerHTML` on the `quote` `div` I output above the code.
- I put all of my code in an enclosing function that I call immediately. This prevents creating any global variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help you're providing to me and taking your time and explaining! I hope I can learn better and be a really good professional! 
The answers you gave me helped me a lot! :)
I hope everyone has a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like the following html:

```
<div id="quote"></div>
<div>
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4" />
</div>
```

and css

```
.image {
   display: none;
}
```

Then you need to do something like this in your `showquote` function:

```
function showquote(){
   document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];
   document.getElementsByTagName('img')[whichquote].style.display="block";
}
```

See the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fYPY7/