# Show Random Javascript Ads on a Website

Tags: javascript, web

I'm searching a way to show javascripts ads randomly on my website and I don't know where to start. The concept is very similar to use a javascript code to show random images, I can do that, but instead of images I want to show javascripts ads.

I've followed [this as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632519/how-do-i-display-randomly-chosen-text-with-an-associated-image) but instead of images I want to add some javascripts code like:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "000000";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Ads";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "00000000000";
amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

So... is possible to invoke a javascript code as a function of another javascript code?

Comment: And what have you tried? What went wrong? What specifically are you asking about? This is far too broad right now.

Comment: Hi @TomReeves thanks for your useless comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. They are the same.

```
if (Math.round(Math.random())) {document.write('put your html inside');}
```

In your case

```
if (Math.round(Math.random())) {document.write('<script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0"; amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "000000"; amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search"; amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart"; amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon"; amzn_assoc_region = "US"; amzn_assoc_title = ""; amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Ads"; amzn_assoc_default_category = "All"; amzn_assoc_linkid = "00000000000"; amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top"</script><script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>');}
```

It is better to split `</script>` into two parts like `</scr'+'ipt>` because when the html interpreter reach that end tag, a script end.